# nullPointerException while linking jsp file to mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

`type Exception report`

`messageInternal Server Error`

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

`GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0`

I'm not able to open the stack trace. the log file under domain is empty. pls help

Comment: This description doesn't help to solve your problem. Do you have any code in your java/jsp file, where you are tried to connect with your jsp to mysql?

Answer (score -1):

`NullPointerException` means you are trying to call a **non-static** method (or an attribute) of an object which is not defined.

**Example:**

```java
String s = "Foo";
System.out.println(s.length());
```

This code prints 3, because the length of `Foo` is 3, and `s` has been initialized as `Foo`.

**Example with `NullPointerException`:**

```java
String s = null;
System.out.println(s.length());
```

Here `s` is `null` and I try to call the method `length()`, which is a **non-static** method. Obviously I will get a `NullPointerException`: there is no sense to get the length of "nothing" (`null`).

Nevertheless, you still can call **static** methods with `s`:

```java
String s = null;
System.out.println(s.valueOf('a'));
```

Prints `a`. Note that it is not a good way to call static methods.

```
The static method valueOf(char) from the type String should be accessed in a static way
```

This warning explains you should access `valueOf(char)` this way:

```java
System.out.println(String.valueOf('a'));
```

Now I let you find the error in your code because you didn't share it.